# Pascal to Mips Code Conversion

Tags: mips, pascal

I'm currently working on a Mips Code Generator for my Pascal Parser (Written in C using Lex / Yacc) . Does anybode know of a Tool out there I can use as a reference in order assure correct Code Generation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [mips simulator](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~larus/spim.html). I used it in school to check and run my mips projcets. One thing I remember is that this simulator has a few commands(to make it easier on us students) that real mips compilers don't. I am pretty sure it is all documented tho.

Comment: Thanks for that! But I was looking for something like: I enter a pascal code in the program and it returns the according Mips code.

Comment: There isn't a 1:1 relationship between source and generated assembly, particularly if an optimiser is involved.

Answer (score 2):

You can build the [GNU Pascal Compiler](http://www.gnu-pascal.de/gpc/h-index.html) for a MIPS target, as a cross-compiler.

Comment: It seems that he's actually writing a compiler, so your answer might not be so helpful.